# Display modally custom keyboard view controller for editing a UITextField

Tags: ios7, uitextfield, uikeyboard

By default when tapping on a `UITextField` iOS will display a default keyboard. Is it possible to bypass this? I would like to display modally a custom view controller on tap on the textField and be able to edit the textField through this controller.

Is there a recommended way?

Comment: Look into the UITextFieldDelegate .. I think the "textFieldShouldBeginEditing" gets called right when the field is tapped... you can then immediately call `[textField resignFirstResponder]` (use options to disabled animated so it doesn't slide up and down but just instantly goes away. Then display your custom keyboard UIView  (add subView) ... or do it modally with a UIViewController if you want? Don't forget textField.delegate = self after adding <UITextFieldDelegate> to your .h!

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw I will explore this path. Thanks

Comment: @tiguero: Any luck with it yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok tried out the exact requirement you asked for:-

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];

    POCModalViewController *objPOCModalViewController = [[POCModalViewController alloc]init];
    [self presentViewController:objPOCModalViewController animated:YES completion:nil];

return NO;
}
```

Where `POCModalViewController` is the controller you want to present.

Comment: is it possible to dismiss the keyboard and let the textField be the first responder?

Comment: The keyboard will not be displayed at all!!

Do you want to show the keyboard?

Comment: i don't want to show the default keyboard; i want to trigger the display of my modal view controller instead but leave the textField as the first responder in the responder chain

Comment: So what will your modal view do?

Comment: My modal view controller will handle the display of different kind of keyboards

Comment: So will it be a custom input view? Will the modal view be full screen?

Comment: Yes the input view should be full screen. I am wondering if i should go with @Divya Bhalodiya solution now. The reason i have this controller is that i want to manage multiple kind of keyboards. May be i should go for one view that manage multiple keyboard views instead.

Comment: Why not use delegates?
Create a textfield in the modal view, & then pass the value of whatever the user typed to the presenter.

Answer (score 2):

Following wil repalce the keyboard as the input view when the user clicks on the UItextField.

```
self.TextField.inputView = "your view ";
```

Comment: That's not the idea: i want to fire a modal view controller when starting editing the text field.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to post the solution i have finally implemented, which is the closest to Footyapps27 solution:

1. I have made the controller that will present the modal controller(which  will contain internally multiple custom keyboard views)  as the `uitextfield` delegate for any UITextField objects contained within the view of my controller.
2. I can now received any notification through the `- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(TWValueInput *)textField` method when a textfield start to be edited:

Within that delegate method I have the following code snippet:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

            MyCustomKeyboardVC* vc = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"customKeyboardController"];
            vc.delegate = self;


            self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;

            [self presentViewController:vc animated:NO completion:nil];

            return NO;
    }
```

returning NO within that method will prevent the default keyboard from being displayed. There is no need actually to call the `resignFirstResponder`on the textfield.

I should point out though that the Apple recommended way to display a custom keyboard is to provide a custom view to the textfield `inputView` property like Divya mentioned. Since i wanted to managed multiple keyboard view entries it was quicker for me to display a custom keyboard controller through the delegate method i mentioned above.